# How to drag in the web browser without moving the page?

Tags: browser

With the stock browser when using a web page has a feature that requires dragging, how do you drag without moving the page?

For example, cropping an image on the Gravatar site requires dragging the boundaries, but whenever I try to, I end up moving the page... but not dragging.

UPDATE: I did notice on a third-party page with Google Maps embedded that the map did drag correctly.  However, the above example still holds.

Comment: I don't know the answer either way but it may be helpful if you specify which browser you are using as there probably are browser specific aspects to this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sites like Gravatar or Twitter's image cropping, I've found that the two finger "pinch" gesture works.

Comment: On my LG Optimus V, that just zooms. Not useful (to me). And I get the same behavior in Skyfire as the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

Double tap to enable drag?